Question about Pro-2 Triceps Extension Machine
On the Pro-2 Triceps Extension machine, should the feet be actually touching the middle thing?  It says the feet should be under the pegs, but should the sides of the feet be touching the middle bar thing?   Thanks.

It does not matter.
It’s often really easy to get caught up worrying about little stuff like a little bit of back rounding in the deadlift or which supination angle is best for a bicep curl. This is smaller even than those things. It just doesn’t matter. Do whatever is comfortable and don’t worry about small stuff like this.

This is a pragmatic and great answer.  For many people, performance of the exercise in a comfortable manner is going to give them the stimulus they want.  Everything else is just minor details which might be important to someone devoted to body building and similar.
